# Why LaunchedEffect call second time when I navigate back?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show some data and simulate loading. For this reason I use LaunchedEffect on the first screen. It works fine, but when I add navigation, LaunchedEffect launch twice.

Navigation: First (LaunchedEffect) -> Second -> Back to first (LaunchedEffect launch again)

I expect that when I return to the first screen LaunchedEffect won't launch and I will immediately see the data.

Sample of LaunchedEffect:

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(...) {
    ...
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        state = State.Loading
        delay(2_000L)
        state = State.Success(...)
    }
}
```

Sample of navigation:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = FIRST_ROTE
) {
    composable(FIRST_ROTE) { FirstScreen(...) }
    composable(SECOND_ROTE) { SecondScreen(...) }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) says

> To call suspend functions safely from inside a composable, use the
> `LaunchedEffect` composable. When `LaunchedEffect` enters the Composition,
> it launches a coroutine with the block of code passed as a parameter.
> The coroutine will be cancelled if `LaunchedEffect` leaves the
> composition. If `LaunchedEffect` is recomposed with different keys, the existing coroutine will be
> cancelled and the new suspend function will be launched in a new
> coroutine.

When you navigate to another screen, the composable is removed from the composition (which means it is not drawn). This is why the `LaunchedEffect` is executed again.

You can control this execution using the state in view model. Something like:

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(vm: YourViewModel) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (vm.someFlag == true) {
            vm.someFlag = false
            state = State.Loading
            delay(2_000L)
            state = State.Success(...)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx) It works! But in this case, when I have a ViewModel, it's better to move all the logic from LaunchEffect to ViewModel

Comment: Yep. Probably to the `init` bloc. But (as always) it depends of your use case :)

Comment: I'm doing the same thing but it still is called again, when I get back to the screen, messing up with my scroll position. Would you please take and look and tell me what I might be doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/2USiryW6

Comment: The information you're storing in `isScreenOpenedWithChapter` must be moved to the `VerseListViewModel`.

Comment: `"If LaunchedEffect is recomposed with different keys"` - But `Unit` key never changes., so why should it be relaunched?

Comment: @levi Because it is not recomposed but composed again. Screen 1 appears, the effect is launched, screen 2 appears, screen 1 leaves the composition tree, we go back to screen 1 which is composed as opposed to re-composed so the effect is launch.

Comment: This is very confusing, it doesn't relaunch if you hit back (closing the app) then re-open the app, but it does if you navigate within your app and back up to the composable

Comment: You just need to understand how `LaunchEffect` works. It runs an coroutine when: the composable function first launches; or when the value of the parameter changes. If you close the app and relaunches it, the `LaunchedEffect` must run again, because you're relaunching the app from zero. When you call another screen inside the app, the previous one is removed from the composition, then when you return to it, it is recomposed and the `LaunchedEffect` is called again...

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @jax have you found any better way ?

Comment: @AtulSharma Try searching for launching 'singletop'